# Using Supersized.js & Channel Images in EE2.7 segment_3 problem

Tags: jquery, channel-images

Im stuck - Ive got a simple portfolio site with a few channels, lists, search and so forth. Im using Supersized with Channel Images to run galleries. I made the first gallery (for the background full screen slides) using an entry in a dedicated channel, uploaded a bunch of images, and used the following code to run the script:

```
 {exp:channel:entries channel="gallery" entry_id="18" enable="custom_fields" parse="inward" limit="1"}


       jQuery(function($){

    /... all the supersized stuff before the slides list .../


    slides  :
       [
       {gallery_image}
       {image : '{image:url:full-size-op}', title : '{image:title}', thumb : '{image:url:thumbnail}'},
       {/gallery_image}

        ]
      });
          });


    {/exp:channel:entries}
```

This works fine* in all sections of the site, except the (single) entry pages. Why is it breaking, has anyone come across anything similar? Even though it has a last trailing comma, that doesn't seem to be a problem. In other words, by segment_3, it breaks, like this: www.mydomain.com/channel/entry/entry_title
(Im running the site without index.php.)

(* - Caveat: in IE8 the script breaks as it returns an error to do with 'thumb_links' being undefined, even though they are. My code isn't the cause of that break, but its a separate issue). UPDATE ON THIS: My code was the cause - removing the last comma sorted this issue out, using backspace="5".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding **[dynamic="no"](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/channel_entries.html#dynamic)** to your {exp:channel:entries} tag

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="gallery" entry_id="18" dynamic="no"}
```

HERE'S INFO FROM THE DOCS

> The ***channel display engine sets some parameters dynamically, based on
>   what is in the URL***. There are times, however, where you do not want
>   the parameters affected by what the URL contains. To override the
>   dynamic nature of the channel tag, use dynamic="no".
>
> This is often useful if you want to list entries in a “sidebar” on
>   your site and have them always be the same ones regardless of which
>   page on your site you visit (main page, archives, comments, etc.). By
>   setting dynamic="no" you will ensure that the list is not affected by
>   anything passed in the URL.

---

Also, you do not need these parameters (enable="custom_fields" parse="inward") on your channel:entries tag. They are not valid... here is a list of [valid parameters](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/channel_entries.html#parameters) for the channel:entries tag.

Comment: Thats done the trick - I wouldn't have thought of it, thank you so much!! 

I used 'enable="custom_fields"' as its used in one of the Channel Images tutorials, I hadn't come across it before, and as I'm not using any other fields, it seemed useful (and works everywhere else in the site). As to 'parse="inward"', I was trying that to load the images earlier in the DOM as it can be useful sometimes. You are right though, I probably dont need them. Id like to know why 'dynamic="no"' cures this problem as had tried lots of things to solve it.

Comment: Great! I added the explanation of the dynamic parameter from the EE docs to my answer... Basically, by default EE looks at the URL for certain things. When it finds a match the tags in the templates will display data based on that match. So on your detail template there was a match based on your segment_3 and it was affecting this tag. Setting dynamic="no" tells EE not to look at the URL for any direction and to use exactly what you've coded in the template.